# What is the purpose of action functions in react redux? Should they all return an action or function that goes to the store/middleware?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, action, redux, react-redux

In the [react redux reddit app example](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html) should the #shouldFetchPosts be part of the actions? It seems weird that it's more of a helper than an actual action, which should return an object that is dispatched to the store. I understand that actions can include functions that serve to send async related things to the middleware, but #shouldFetchPosts doesn't seem to fit this purpose nor one of a traditional action. Is there a better way of organizing this function? Should it of not been abstracted out at all in the first place?

```
function fetchPosts(reddit) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestPosts(reddit))
    return fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${reddit}.json`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(reddit, json)))
  }
}

function shouldFetchPosts(state, reddit) {
  const posts = state.postsByReddit[reddit]
  if (!posts) {
    return true
  }
  if (posts.isFetching) {
    return false
  }
  return posts.didInvalidate
}

export function fetchPostsIfNeeded(reddit) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (shouldFetchPosts(getState(), reddit)) {
      return dispatch(fetchPosts(reddit))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's used when the app first start or when app switched from background, in first case you have to pull data, in second, you already have data in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch. And yes, you're right! `shouldFetchPosts` is not an action. It's a helper function. It should not be placed with action creators in the first place. One may think that the redux examples have a huge scope for improvement. But on the brighter side, it's a great way to learn things too. You spotted a mistake in their code. You should go ahead and correct it in your sample project.